# Need to extract the Pure HTML Data from the XML File

Tags: java, html, xml, parsing

The  question is, whenever we have html tags having many level html elements as mentioned in example below for contentData tag

```
 Example XML:
```

```
<textContent>
    <contentData>
        <p><b><i><u>SubStructureElement_RTE_</u></i></b></p>
    </contentData>
</textContent>
```

Weed to extract them as it is. 
But when we use `element.getTextContent()` to extract the html content, it is not working as expected, meaning  i am getting the output as be

```
 SubStructureElement_RTE_
```

whereas, the expected output is

```
 Ex: <p><b><i><u>SubStructureElement_RTE_</u></i></b></p>
```

This is what i had tried earlier...

```
NodeList textContentBodyList=textContent.getElementsByTagName(BODY_NODE);
Element textContentBody = (Element) textContentBodyList.item(0);
NodeList contentDataList = textContentBody.getElementsByTagName(CONTENT_DATA_NODE);
if(contentDataList!=null && contentDataList.getLength()>0) {    
     textContentBody= (Element) contentDataList.item(0);
}

contentDataList = textContentBody.getElementsByTagName(P_NODE);
if(contentDataList!=null && contentDataList.getLength()>0){
    textContentBody= (Element) contentDataList.item(0);
}
eachNewElement.setArtworkContent(textContentBody.getTextContent().trim());
```

Question: Need to get the complete html as it is. I have tried as mentioned above.

Later i have figured out the solution for the same, and the answer goes like this.

```
public String getCompleteRTECopyText(NodeList nodeList, StringBuilder completeText) 
{
    if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            Node tempNode = nodeList.item(i);

            if(tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            {
                completeText.append(tempNode.getTextContent().replaceAll("\t", "").replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "\n"));
                continue;
            }

            if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                completeText.append("<"+tempNode.getNodeName()+">");

            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                getCompleteRTECopyText(tempNode.getChildNodes(), completeText);
            }

            completeText.append("</"+tempNode.getNodeName()+">");
        }
    } 

    return completeText.toString();
}
```

Thanks for posting 
some bits and pieces from stack overflow, i took some help from stack overflow, i have written the code as per requirements and it works,

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "_Question: In this line, i am trying to extract the html content_" This is not a question.

Comment: Have you tried with cloneNode(true) instead of getTextContent()?

Comment: Great - so, what's stopping you?

Comment: I need to extract the html content as raw text from the XML. Whereas textContentBody.getTextContent() will give me only the text content rather that the whole html data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getTextContent() returns the content *inside* each element, without the element tags.

To write out XML as elements, you can use a DOM serializer:

```
DOMImplementation impl =
    textContentBody.getOwnerDocument().getImplementation();
DOMImplementationLS ls =
    (DOMImplementationLS) impl.getFeature("+LS", "3.0");
LSSerializer serializer = ls.createLSSerializer();
serializer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", false);
String contentData = serializer.writeToString(textContentBody);
```

Or, you can use an identity transform:

```
StringWriter contentDataWriter = new StringWriter();
Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
xformer.transform(new DOMSource(textContentBody),
                  new StreamResult(contentDataWriter));
String contentData = contentDataWriter.toString();
```

If you want to remove extra whitespace, as in your example, you can do:

```
contentData = contentData.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: This will give me the data with the contenData tag, i want to extract from that tag as well. For Example:: <contenData> <br/> Raghav <br/></contenData >, I need output as  <br/> Raghav <br/>

Comment: I have a solution for my own question i have asked.